# Can VBA keep adding cells until the sum of those added cells are greater than another cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to keep adding cells in a column (B) until the sum of those added values is equal to or greater than another cell value. Then Hide the rows that haven't been added.

Picture is attached via Stacks Overflows picture software, IMGUR.

Appreciate any info or direction!!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrthL.png]

Comment: If you add rows until the sum is equal to the value in column C, why would you have extra rows? It may be helpful to see what the starting point is. Also any code you have so far would let us avoid redoing already existing code

Comment: What does "Then Hide the rows that haven't been added" should mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this VBA Procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideExtraRows()
Dim PartRange As Range, cl As Range, PartTxt As String
Dim BOQty As Double, POQty As Double
PartTxt = ""

On Error Resume Next
Set PartRange = Application.InputBox("Select the Parts Range to hide extra rows", _
                "Select Range", , , , , , 8)
If PartRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo 0

For Each cl In PartRange
    If cl <> PartTxt Then
        PartTxt = cl
        BOQty = cl.Offset(, 2)
        POQty = cl.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        POQty = POQty + cl.Offset(, 1)
        If POQty > BOQty Then cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly!! How do you get good at VBA? I have been doing youtube videos and tutorials but hasnt been enough to make this procedure. Any advice for a beginner?